# How to open a specific screen in the app using Deep Linking at Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am wanting to access a screen in my app project, by mobile, through a URL that was sent to the email.

The project is being developed at the expo and I am trying to use the "linking" of the same expo, I consulted the expo documentation about linking (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/), but couldn't make the exact screen open.

In app.json looks like this:

```
"expo": {
  "scheme": "myApp",
}
```

In the route I left:

```
ExchangePassword : {
  screen: ExchangePassword ,
  path: "exchangePassword /"
}
```

I'm trying to access through a URL like this

```
<a href="myApp://ExchangePassword"> Click Here </a>
```

But when I access the link on the phone it opens the main project screen and not the password change screen.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as routing library? Because it's in the that library you have to define where a deep linking URL is supposed to go. Check their documentation for deep linking

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:
   path: "exchangePassword /"

with:
   path: "/exchangePassword"

and replace:

with:
    //uppercase E to lowercase e